# how to enable/disable child elements in django template

Tags: python-2.7, django-templates

Actually i don't know about javascript and jquery.

I want to enable/disable child elements in django template
form field is generated dynamically

so,I have organization and its related designation, see structure like this

```
[checkbox]"ABC"
    [checkbox]"CEO"
    [checkbox]"COO"
[checkbox]"xyz"
    [checkbox]"Manager"
    [checkbox]"staff"
```

my code snippet is

```
<form method="post">
    {% for org in orgs %}
        <tr><input type="checkbox" value="{{org.id}}" name="add2orgs" onclick="disablediv({{org.id}},this)" /> {{org.name}}</tr><br/>
        {%for org in org.designations %}
          <tr>  <td><input type="checkbox" name="designations2add" value="{{obj.id}}" disabled="true"/></td>
             <td>{{obj.title}}</td>
             <td>{{obj.description}}</td>
     </tr>
        {%endfor%}
    {%%endfor}
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

**file.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function disablediv(id,nme)
    {
        var eleid=nme.id;
        if(document.getElementById(eleid).checked){
          //what will be code to enable all field in div? 
          document.getElementById(id).style.display="block";


        }else{
              //what will be code to disble all field in div   
             document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";

        }

    }
```

now, what is i want to do is 
if i unchecked org checkbox, then its all child designations checkbox should be unchecked

Thnx in advance ..

Answer (score 0):

using javascript

```
function disablediv(divid,thiss)
{
    var cid=thiss.id;
    if(document.getElementById(cid).checked){
        var nodes = document.getElementById(divid).getElementsByTagName('*');
        for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
            nodes[i].disabled = false;
        }
        document.getElementById(divid).style.display="block";

    }else{
        var nodes = document.getElementById(divid).getElementsByTagName('*');
        for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
            nodes[i].disabled = true;
            nodes[i].checked = false;
        }
        document.getElementById(divid).style.display="none";

    }

}
```

know looking for jquery ...